# Convert email to Contact

Tags: contacts

I have a text file of a list of contacts in the form `Name  <emailaddress>`.

I would like to convert this to a Contact group - or at least convert each to a contact.

Currently I have to edit into Name Surname emailaddress and post individual fields.

Comment: Have you tried left(), mid(), right() and find() ? Perhaps a few examples would help?

Comment: Turn it into a VCF file, then import the VCF file.  https://docs.fileformat.com/email/vcf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very many (most?) email clients (including Apple's Mail) understand `Name <emailaddress>`.
I felt sure that it should be possible to import to Contacts, but failing to find anything wrote a quick & dirty program to convert to VCF (which Contacts does understand).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# Convert file of email addresses to vcf file
# File should contain:-
# Name Surname <emailaddress>
# 2022-04-17

use Modern::Perl '2015';
use autodie;

my $listfile = 'mailfile.txt';  # replace with path to file of email addresses
my $vcffile = 'listfile.vcf';

open my $fh, '<', $ listfile;
open my $tmp_fh, '>', $vcffile;

while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    chomp $line;
    $line=~ s/\s+$//;   # remove right spaces

    my ($fn, $email) = split /</, $line;    # split line
    $email =~ s/>//;

    my ($name, $surname) = split(' ', $fn, 2);
    $surname=~ s/\s+$//;    # remove right spaces

    print $tmp_fh "BEGIN:VCARD\n";
    print $tmp_fh "VERSION:3.0\n";
    print $tmp_fh "N:$surname;$name;;;\n";
    print $tmp_fh "FN:$fn\n";
    print $tmp_fh "EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=HOME;type=pref:$email\n";
    print $tmp_fh "END:VCARD\n";
}

close($tmp_fh);
```